# Python strings immutable?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, immutability

Python strings are supposed to be immmutable just like integers. Consider this:

```
>>> num1 = 34
>>> num2 = 36
>>> id(num1)
505894832
>>> num4 = 34
>>> id(num4)
505894832
```

`num4` has the exact same ID as num1, which means they are pointing to the same thing. Shouldn't the same thing happen with strings ? Am confused with:

```
>>> name = "Sumeet"
>>> id(name)
35692000
>>> name = "Ali"
>>> id(name)
35926912
>>> naam = "Sumeet"
>>> id(naam)
35926848
```

Shouldn't the last output be:  `35692000`?

Comment: Immutable just means they can't be modified. It has nothing to do with whether there are multiple copies of the same string.

Comment: Also, python interns low integers and reuses them. They are immutable after all. You really only need *1* copy of the number `1`..

Comment: So, for strings do we need multiple copies of say the same "Hello"... They are also immutable ?

Comment: Also: Python can *reuse* memory addresses. `id()` is not guaranteed to be unique.

Comment: Thanks for the information, thus it is not something we can be sure of. The system can reuse that memory for something else or maybe it can be garbage collected if no active reference is there in memory.

Comment: Why does this concern you?

Comment: Look up the word immutable before you go any further!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The fact that several variables have the same id has nothing much to do with the actual objects being immutable.

In fact, this can happen safely (saving memory), due to their immutability.

Let's assume that a string in python was not immutable, you declared:

`a = 'abc'`

`b = 'abc'`

If you changed `a`, that would mean that `b` would either reference a completely different object (duplicating the memory needed to represent the same literal string), or that, when `a` was changed, the whole object would have to be copied over in order to make the change (so that b wouldn't be affected).

Since the strings are immutable, both variables can safely point to the same object. Any change to an immutable data structure creates a new structure, and the reference that was pointing towards it is changed to the new one, leaving all other references to the "old" structure unchanged. The absence of side effects in immutable data structures greatly diminishes the possibility of errors occurring due to a shared structure/object being changed somewhere else in your code.

Answer (score 3):

CPython interns some very small integers and very small strings, but you can't rely on this since it's implementation dependent.

So, here are some counterexamples to your findings:

```
>>> a = 123456
>>> b = 123456
>>> id(a)
30497296
>>> id(b)
30496144
>>> a = "hey"
>>> b = "hey"
>>> id(a)
44067112
>>> id(b)
44067112
```

Comment: Does that mean, "The value may or may not be kept safe at that address" ..?

Comment: @NikhilKhullar: The question doesn't really make sense from a Python perspective. The language doesn't exposes "addresses" or "pointers" to be kept safe or not. All you need to know is that strings, tuples and integers are immutable and that lists/dictionaries/sets are not. Since you can't mutate a string, binding multiple names to the same string is safe, yes, but you needn't be concerned about that. You do need to know that you should never use `is` for equality comparison, only `==`, because `"hey" is "hey"` may be `True` whereas `"Sumeet" is "Sumeet"` may be `False`.

Answer (score 2):

No it doesn't point to the same thing, for one clear and concise reason.

When you do this:

```
name = 'Sumeet'
```

You essentially create a new `string` object and bind it to the `name` reference. When you do this:

```
naam = 'Sumeet'
```

You are again creating a **NEW** `string` object and bind it to the `naam` reference. In order for them to point to the same object, you should have done this:

`naam = name`

This makes `naam` refer to the same object that `name` refers to.

---

Regarding the integers, the `CPython` implementation of Python has a feature that caches small integers. For instance, according to [this source](http://choorucode.wordpress.com/2012/05/01/integer-caching-in-python/) python 3.2 caches integer objects from `-5` to `256`.

Comment: Precisely the information I needed. The concept is clear now, that caching was confusing me...

Comment: @NikhilKhullar Glad to have been of help.